# Indexing nested entites with Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Given a file with the following two lines of Json:

```
{"baseId": "1", "reports:"[{"name":"tom", "age:40"}]}  
{"baseId": "1", "reports:"[{"name":"mandy", "age:12"}]}
```

I want Logstash to insert these into Elasticsearch as one entity:

```
{"baseId":"1",
   "reports":[
      {"name":"tom", "age":40},
      {"name":"mandy", "age":12},
   ]
}
```

not two separate entities, as will happen by default.

In essence, when Logstash sees the first line, it would need to create an entry with an ID of 1 (`baseId`). When Logstash processes the second line, it must update the existing entity and add a new nested `report` object.

How is it possible to configure Elasticsearch and Logstash to do this?
It is not an option to simply merge the two lines in the source file, as the two lines will be inserted at separate times or come from different sources.

Thanks